# Default URL settings wrong when using 'cv core:install'?

Tags: installation, cv

I have tried to create a clean setup using cv core:install. The setup did not work properly due to the following:

1. The 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL' variable did not end with a slash, although the comments above it suggest it.
2. The paths were defined to 'public_html' which in most cases is a link to 'domains/[domain]/private_html'. I had to change that to the absolute private path.

I do not know if this is due to my environment, although I think the first one is a bug.

Comment: what sort of hosting is this using?

Comment: I have a VPS which I maintain myself.